# Can't see the the new value with $watch Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is my Plunker : [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/bucIAhkjJxrZWBNmtzXe?p=preview) .
here is my code:
**Controller :**

```
$scope.myDate='13930101';
    $scope.showDate=function() {
      PersianDatePicker.Show('thisDate', $scope.myDate);
      
    };

  $scope.$watch( 'myDate',
            function(newValue, oldValue){
                console.log('myDate Changed');
                console.log(newValue);
                console.log(oldValue);
            }
    );
```

**Html** :

```
  <input type="text" id="thisDate" ui-mask="9999/99/99"
          ng-model="myDate"  />


    <input type="button" value="test" ng-click="showDate()">
```

The problem is : i can't see the changes for this :  `$scope.myDate='13930101';`

**Or**

My codes are wrong!
Any idea ? Thanks ahead

Comment: It works. Why do you think it doesn't?

Comment: no , it doesnt work, did u have a look on the console @lujcon

Comment: yes,check it in console please

Comment: bad/no documentation: https://jspersiandatepicker.codeplex.com/

Comment: yes bad documentation , any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

Hay the problem is that the watcher is only for the input field, if you type something directly in the input field, the watcher triggers. But if you choose a date from the picker. it doesnt trigger.

Comment: oh.it's true , do you have any idea ? Update : should i create a directive for that ?

Comment: you have to synchronize the input field with the selected date. so you have to add the date to a scope, I unfortunately  dont know the options of the persiandatepicker...

Answer (score 1):

This lib contains [no documentation](https://jspersiandatepicker.codeplex.com/). From inspecting the [scripts](https://jspersiandatepicker.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Scripts/PersianDatePicker.js) I see there is no other API function than `Show()` and therefore no callback like `onSelect()` which lets you bind the chosen date to your scope variable.

I suggest to use another lib like [this one](https://github.com/AminRahimi/angular-bootstrap-persian-datepicker) which is already *angularized*.

Comment: thanks for sharing your time with me , i've tried that before , when i try to type directly in input , it can't convert correctly into popup .
 Thanks anyway

Comment: try it again and open other question if it does not work